# Can no longer enter information to a db when using primefaces

Tags: mysql, jsf, primefaces

i have been using the code below to enter some details into a mysql table, this was working perfectly fine, except i wanted to add more validation and make it look more professional so i decided to use a primefaces library for this, while it does submit the data, it no longer passes it to the db, why is this aas the only thing i have changed is the way the user enters data for looks

heres the working original

```html
<h:form>
    <h:messages showDetail="true" /> 
    <h:outputText value="Enter Id : "/>
    <h:inputText value="#{user.userID}"/>
    <br></br>

    <h:outputText value="Enter Name : " />
    <h:inputText value="#{user.name}" />
    <br></br>

    <h:outputText value="Enter your address : "/>
    <h:inputText value="#{user.address}" />   
    <br></br>

    <h:outputText value="Enter Created Date : "/>
    <h:inputText value="#{user.created_date}">
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    </h:inputText>
    <br></br>
    <h:outputText value="Enter email address : "/>

    <h:inputText id="email" value="#{user.email}" 
        size="20" required="true" label="Email Address">
        <f:validator validatorId="richard.test.EmailValidator" />
    </h:inputText>
    <br></br>
    <h:message for="email" style="color:red" />       

    <h:commandButton value="Insert" action="#{user.add}"/>
</h:form>
```

This is the improved looking one but no longer works

```html
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">  
        <p:panel id="panel" header="New Person" style="margin-bottom:10px;">  
            <p:messages id="messages" />  
            <h:panelGrid columns="3">  

                <h:outputLabel for="name" value="name: *" />  
                <p:inputText id="name"   
                             value="#{user.name}" required="true" label="name"/>  
                <p:message for="name" />  

                <h:outputLabel for="address" value="address:  *" />  
                <p:inputText id="address"   
                             value="#{user.address}" required="true" label="address"/>  
                <p:message for="address" />  

                <h:outputLabel for="Id" value="Id  *" />  
                <p:inputText id="Id"   
                             value="#{user.userID}" required="true" label="Id"/>  
                <p:message for="Id" />  

                <h:outputLabel for="Date" value="Date   *" />  
                <p:inputText id="Date"   
                             value="#{user.created_date}" required="true" label="Date"/>  

                <p:message for="Id" /> 

            </h:panelGrid>  
        </p:panel>  

        <p:commandButton value="Ajax Submit" update="panel,display" id="ajax"  
                         actionListener="#{user.add}" styleClass="ui-priority-primary"/>  

        <!--<p:commandButton value="Non-Ajax Submit" actionListener="{user.add}"   
                ajax="false" />  

        -->

        <p:panel id="display" header="Information" style="margin-top:10px;">  
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">  


                <h:outputText value="name " />  
                <h:outputText value="#{user.name}" />  
            </h:panelGrid>  
        </p:panel>  

    </h:form>
```

What would cause this from happening? The backing bean etc have not been changed at all.

Comment: Looks like a problem in your database configuration. This problem is not related to JSF nor PrimeFaces at all.

Comment: Try put an `System.out.print("hello")` on `add` method, to see if its printed. If it prints, yeah, i agreewith @LuiggiMendoza, if not, we will try find the real problem.

Comment: What exactly does not work. Your info is quite vague. Is it maybe just the buttons actionlistener that is not invoked?